# ggvis plots rendered using bind_shiny() aren't reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, ggvis

I think I'm missing some basic aspect of ggvis + shiny.

Following the tutorials, plots are constructed in server.R using a series of %>% pipes, ending with bind_shiny, which associates the plot with an identifier that can be referred to in ui.R

What I don't get though is that the plot itself is not reactive in the way that code within renderTable(), renderText() or reactive() will be. So if I want to refer to an input parameter like input$x in defining the plot, it won't work, I'll get an error saying `"Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"`.

For example, if 'input' is the input parameter to the shinyServer function, I might have a plot that looks like:

```
dataframe %>% ggvis(~ aval, ~ bval) %>% layer_points %>% layer_paths(x = ~xv, y = ~ yv, data = data.frame(xv = c(0, 0), yv = c(0, input$maxValParam)))
```

where layeR_points is used to plot data in dataframe and layer_paths is being used to draw a vertical line up to the maxValParam value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25060999/3618859) might be useful.

It looks like in order to reference your `input$maxValParam` inside a ggvis() function, the entire ggvis function needs to be wrapped in a reactive.
blatantly ripping off the above answer, yours might look something like:

```
reactive({
  dataframe %>% 
      ggvis() #rest of plotting code %>% 
      add_axis("x", title = input$maxValParam)
}) %>% bind_shiny("plot")
```

Comment: any idea why ggvis is implemented using bind_shiny() function while the shiny reactive plots have their own renderXXX() function? This works but it's kind of confusing that it's not consistent.

Comment: I have no idea... I think it has to do with ggvis being interactive as a standalone, so it probably needs different methods.  Ggvis documentation might have a clue. Or just ask Hadley.