# Reactive input to ggvis in R-markdown cause quit

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggvis

I'm trying to use R-markdown with shiny to do some interactive visualization. The file let the user specify a bunch of data files and use reactive shiny expression to get a processed dataframe, `data()`. I can use `data()` with `renderPlot` to correctly plot out a bunch of graphs(like `heatmap.2`, `plot`). However, when I try using `ggvis` to plot the reactive data, the generation of the html always quit at the ggvis code chunk.
I tried the answer to [How is data passed from reactive Shiny expression to ggvis plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011544/how-is-data-passed-from-reactive-shiny-expression-to-ggvis-plot). But both of the two methods in the answer led to "Quitting from lines". Here's my code:

```
reactive({
    data %>% ggvis(~pcomp, ~variances) %>% 
    layer_points()%>%
    layer_bars(fill := "gray", opacity := 0.5) %>%
    layer_lines()
}) %>% bind_shiny("plot1")

ggvisOutput("plot1")
```

Here's my code based on the other method:

```
data %>% ggvis(~pcomp, ~variances) %>% 
    layer_points()%>%
    layer_bars(fill := "gray", opacity := 0.5) %>%
    layer_lines()
```

I'm using R-Studio Version 0.99.441, R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18), shiny_0.12.1, ggvis 0.4.

Comment: Example data could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to pure Shiny and retried this, instead of using `reactive`, I wrapped the whole thing in `observe`. This works perfectly.